# jquery small problem

Tags: jquery

how can i change this: (this script says that it should hide #writeComment if #tryout is checked )

```
$('#tryout').click(function () {
  $('#writeComment').toggle(!$(this).attr('checked'));
});
```

Now i dont want to have a checkbox that you check, but instead this link

```
<a id="tryout">Click to vote</a>
```

so then when you click on this "link", #writeComment hides...

Comment: What? This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Wow something went wrong please check my updated answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) without a boolean, like this:

```
$('#tryout').click(function() {
  $('#writeComment').toggle();
});
```

Just set the `display` state to what you want it to be initially, internally [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) checks if it's [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/), and if it is, calls [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), otherwise it calls [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: really fast, thank you.. i was trying to make a fadein     $('#writecomment').fadeIn('slow', toggle()); seems like i dont understand nothing of jquery..

Comment: @Azzyh - For a fade toggle, do `.animate({ opacity: 'toggle' });` :)